# Clarification on the script P2SH, how is executed to Bitcoin core?

Tags: transactions, script, transaction-verification, p2sh

This question is a continuation of the [my post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/90416/how-does-this-simple-script-use-the-op-checksig-opcode/90417#90417) yesterday.

Today I have a question on P2SH execution so, an example of the script should be this

```
OP_0 <A Signature> <B Signature> OP_2 <Public key A> <Public key B> 
<Public key C> OP_3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
OP_HASH160 <ScriptSig Hash> OP_EQUAL
```

or if used the P2SH key should be is this (I think in this script left-hand something to convert the hash160 inside the P2SH key, right?)

```
OP_0 <A Signature> <B Signature> OP_2 <Public key A> <Public key B> 
<Public key C> OP_3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
OP_HASH160 <P2SH key> OP_EQUAL
```

Now if I have understood well the simulation of the execution is divided into two phases

1. The hash `scriptSig` is equal to hash inside the `scriptPubKey`

Simulation

- Put on the `scriptSig` on the stack, so the stack now is `<A sig> <B sig> <A pubkey> <B pubkey> <C pubkey>`
- Calculate the `hash160` with the data inside the stack, so now the stack status is `<scriptSig hash>`
- Put on the `scriptSig` hash expected, now the stack status is `<hash scriptsig> <hash scriptsigexpected>`
- return the result of the operator `OP_EQUAL` (true or false)

---

2. the `scriptSig` will execute such as the script multi-signature

Simulation

- put on the stack the `scriptSig`, the stack status is `<A Signature> <B Signature>`
- push the public keys, that stack status is `<A Signature> <B Signature> <Public key A> <Public key B> <Public key C>`
- apply the `OP_CHECKMULTISIG` operator and get the result

My questions are:

- With the P2SH key, the execution is the same? if not, what is the form of the P2SH with the P2SH key?

Also, I read this [post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/73361/how-does-a-p2sh-script-get-executed) but I don't think contains this answer.

If my example script is wrong, I'm sorry to give me a corrections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go over this step by step. Suppose say you want to lock some bitcoins in a 2-of-3 multi-sig.

**Locking steps**

1. Create a multi-sig script: `OP_2 <pub_key 1> <pub_key2> <pub_key3> OP_3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG`.
2. Hash the multi-sig script with `HASH160` which gives you `multi-sig_scripthash`.
3. Base58Check the `multi-sig_scripthash` with version 0x05 giving you an address starting with `3...`.
4. The `scriptPubKey` will be `OP_HASH160 <multi-sig_scripthash> OP_EQUAL`.

**Unlocking Steps**

1. Your stack will start at `<signatures><redeemScript>`. The signature is `OP_0 <sig_A> <sig_B>` and `redeemScript` is `OP_2 <pub_key 1> <pub_key2> <pub_key3> OP_3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG`.
2. Since v0.3.7, Bitcoin Core executes the unlocking script first and looks at the resulting stack. So your `<signatures>` and `<redeemScript>` are evaluated together first. This would result in a multi-signature evaluation.
3. In normal cases the above step should just return 1 as signatures satisfy the redeemScript. But with P2SH there is a caveat added by [BIP-16](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0016.mediawiki). Whenever you have a `OP_HASH160 <hash> OP_EQUAL` locking script, it serves as a P2SH identifier. So before the evaluation of `<signatures>` with `<redeemScript>` the `redeemScript` is copied from the stack to another one. Then the evaluation is done with what is on stack (`<signatures><redeemScript>` in our case). If successful, replace the current stack with the just `redeemScript`. Hence, instead of 1 you have `<redeemScript>` at the top of the stack.
4. You run `OP_HASH160` on the redeemScript. Stack is now `<hash160_of_redeemScript>`
5. You push `<expectedredeemScripthash>`. Stack is now `<hash160_of_redeemScript><expectedredeemScripthash>`
6. You run `OP_EQUAL` resulting in evaluation and returning 1 to the top of the stack.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have a question, exist some operator inside bitcoin script for calculate the Base58Check?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo Base58check encoding is for human readability. It is for humans to distinguish whether the address generated/being sent to is P2PKH or P2SH. It does not have any meaning inside the software.

Comment: My fault, I have jump this note "Note: If you just insert the address starting with 3, the software will automatically calculate the scriptPubKey as above."

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo What I meant was, as a user you just enter an address starting with 3. The **wallet** software then transitions it to the scriptPubKey.

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo as further clarification, addresses are not sent over the wire nor stored in the blockchain. Addresses are only for human readability. So when a user enters an address starting with 3.., the wallet software decodes the base58check, extracts the redeem_script_hash and uses `OP_HASH160 <redeem_scripthash> OP_EQUAL` as the scriptPubKey. If your address began with 1, the wallet software will use `OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <redeem_scripthash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG` as scriptPubKey.

Comment: Yes thanks for your clarification, you have help me :)